# Reading a test bank file into 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a Java program, that reads a test bank file to a 2D array. The test bank is formatted like [this](http://textuploader.com/ddglr/). Here's a sample:

```
Java is an object-oriented programming language. An object-oriented language:

(a)Uses structured programming.

(b)Views a program as consisting of objects which communicate through interactions.

(c)Functionally breaks down problems into smaller, more manageable problems.

(d)All of the above.

B 

In Java, the equal sign is used as the ___________ operator.

(a)increment

(b)decrement

(c)assignment

(d)negation

C

In Java, source code is compiled into object code called ______________.
*...)
```

The test bank has lots of questions.

I'm trying to put the questions in the first dimension of the array and the answers in the second dimension, there are 4 answers and the correct answer letter is after the choices.

The problem is I want to assign variables to the questions and the answer and the correct letter but I have no idea where to start! :(

I want first a method to read the file then assign a variable, is there such a thing?

edit :
this is some information from the instructor 
[picture about the test bank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tD6d.png)

Thank you all.

Comment: You could make a class called "Question" which has the attributes you just described. Then make a 1D array of all the question objects.

Comment: What's the problem? Read how to create a [mcve] so we can help you better.

Comment: im not really good in java, but i want to create an array of these question, so i can create a test out of it, and make the user take the test, by showing 10 Question and the user answer by choosing from the answers, then his final grade will print out of 10. but i have no idea where to start, i have uploaded a picture it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is i want to assign variables to the questions and the answer and the correct letter

You should modify your design. You required a list of [question (String), 4 answer choices (String) and index of correct answer]. That cannot fit in 2d array so :

You can begin as follows:

```
class Question
{
    String text;
    List<String> answerChoice;
    int answerIndex;
}
```

Now, you can have a `List<Question>`.